# Using Spring @Repository beans into Micronaut applicatiion

Tags: spring, micronaut

I am working on a Micronaut application that needs to use a jar which is a Spring Repository ( @Repository ). So, basically I need to inject a spring bean into micronaut. I have added that jar to my build.gradle.

This is the Micronaut code where I expect bean to be injected.

```
@Inject
lateinit var receiptRepository: ReceiptRepository
```

This is how it is declared in the JAR:

```
@Repository
public interface ReceiptRepository extends CrudRepository<Receipt, String> {
}
```

How can I use this Repository in my Micronaut app.

I tried a lot but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Are you wanting to inject a Spring managed bean or do you want to create a Micronaut managed bean from the class in your `.jar` file?

Comment: I want to create a Micronaut managed bean from the class in the .jar file which is, by the way, not a class but interface ( for which Spring provides an implementation).

Comment: updated the question

Comment: If what you want is for that to be treated as a Micronaut Data Repository, the answer is no you can't do that.  The interface would need to be compiled with our annotation processors on the compile time classpath in order for that to work.  If that isn't what you want, then I don't think I know the answer.